# How can I elegantly avoid making multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following element on my page:

```
<div class=playerCard>
   Card Type: <select class="cardType"></select>
   Card Attack: <select class="cardAttack"> </select>
   Card Defense: <select class="cardDefense"></select>
</div>
```

For each of the three dropdowns of the playerCard, there is an API call that returns the content for that dropdown element. Each of the API calls return an array of strings. For example, getCardTypes would return ["Joker", "Wrath", "Titan"]

```
Card Type is an API call that returns a list of valid card types (getCardTypes)
Card Attack is an API call that returns valid attacks based on the type (getAttack(cardType))
Card Defense is an API call that returns valid defenses based on type and attack (getDefense(cardType, attack))
```

With the likelihood of having upwards of 100+ playerCards on my page, I want to avoid making 3 API calls for every card. That seems ugly!

What are some best practices to deal with this dilemma? What I've thought of so far is to create some global variables and initialize them one time (on page load), and write some code to replicate the functionality behind the getAttack and getDefense API calls. However, nearly every page on the internet says globals are bad bad bad! What else can I do?

Example workflow:

User adds a new playerCard to the page.

We hit the getCardTypes API call which returns an array of strings, which we use to populate the Card Type dropdown.

User selects a Card Type.

We hit the getAttack API call passing in Card Type, and we receive back an array of strings (valid attacks), which we use to populate the Card Attack dropdown.

User selects Card Attack.

We hit the getDefense API call passing in Card Type and Attack, and we receive back an array of strings (valid defense), which we use to populate the Card Defense dropdown.

User selects a Card Defense..

Comment: are you able to change the API?

Comment: @Bricky how would changing the API reduce the number of requests to it?

Comment: Just load all possible combinations in one api call, than use Javascript to filter?

Comment: Creating an endpoint that returns multiple cards, if it does not already exist.

Comment: And for @Martelyn You haven't even described what you API call does. Without knowing what it returns, its nearly impossible to tell you how to handle this better. If it sets some defined variables, then use Javascript. But please paste the wanted outcome, and current response from your calls

Comment: @OleHaugset Each of the API calls return arrays of strings, which are the options that the user can then select.

Comment: Okay, so if by selecting one value in a select-container should predetermine the values in another, and you want to reduce the number of API-calls, then print them all to dom, and use javascript to choose which ones to show. As long as we're not talking thousands, then you should be fine.

Comment: If the card data doesn't change much store the data locally and synchronize it occasionally with server

Answer (score 0):

Wrap APIs into different services!

```
getCardType => return promise which resolve card types
getCardAttack => return promise which resolve card attak
getCardDefense => return promise which resolve card defense
```

To reduce http request, you can cache datas, just call every API once~

You can also combine services to reduce code logic.

```
get CardInfo => return promise which resolve an object contains card type,card attack,card defense
```